# I thought I wanted an infinite loop. What kind of loop do I want?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I wanted to highlight every occurrence of a word in textview. I thought that I wanted an infinite loop, because I wanted it to always scan entry text for the keyword. I am learning that may not be the case. What kind of loop am I looking for that accomplishes the goal of continuously scanning the text?

```
while (range.location == textView.text.characters.count) {
    text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value:UIColor.redColor(), range: nsString.rangeOfString("red"))
    text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A infinite loop is not what you want.
you want to be notified when a user makes a change to the text then to loop over the text and colour as you need.

Take a look at the UITextViewDelegate methods. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/

specifically

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

That happens when the user resigns the responder to the textview

or a better experience would be to do as they are typing to colour the text.

`UITextField` has the action `UIControlEventEditingChanges` which gets fired upon every text edit.